# Is it possible to pipe multiple inputs into one program?

Tags: c, bash, pipe

I have a C program that takes in 2 separate inputs through the read(0,buffer,size(buffer)) function.
They take two different inputs. Is it possible, through bash command only, to pipe two pytho -c or perl -e scripts into the C program? Or do I have to change its source code? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably use separate file descriptors to read the streams from C - there is only one stdin yet you could merge things prior if you really wanted to but then more work to separate unless you don't need to separate them.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a command group

```
{
   echo "First command"
   echo "Second command"
} | nl
```

Or on one line for your interactive editing convenience:

```
{ echo "First"; echo "Second"; } | nl
```

Comment: I had no idea you could do this ...

Comment: Or a subshell: `(echo foo; echo bar) | nl`.  But I like yours.

Comment: This is a concatenation; not sure it responds to the question.